# Wordpress: Automatically change specific URLs in posts

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have found a solution to change links in my wordpress theme, but not the links in the content. How is it possible to get the URL in the content, so I can also changed them?

I need to use `the content` filter. But how is it possible to change URLs like apple.com/test/ apple.com/test-123/, apple.com, microsoft.com, microsoft.com/test/. The function should also change correctly every matched URL in the content.

```
add_filter('the_content ', 'function_name');
```

The [answer of a similiar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/357790/change-links-automatically-to-affiliate-links) unfortunately doesn't work.

This is my working solution to change links, but not the links in the content.

```php
add_filter('rh_post_offer_url_filter', 'link_change_custom');
function link_change_custom($offer_post_url){

$shops= array(
        array('shop'=>'apple.com','id'=>'1234'),
        array('shop'=>'microsoft.com','id'=>'5678'),
        array('shop'=>'dell.com','id'=>'9876'), 
    );
    foreach( $shops as $rule ) {
        if (!empty($offer_post_url) && strpos($offer_post_url, $rule['shop']) !== false) {      
            $offer_post_url = 'https://www.network.com/promotion/click/id='.$rule['id'].'-yxz?param0='.rawurlencode($offer_post_url);
}    
    }
$shops2= array(
        array('shop'=>'example.com','id'=>'1234'),
        array('shop'=>'domain2.com','id'=>'5678'),
        array('shop'=>'domain3','id'=>'9876'),  
    );
    foreach( $shops2 as $rule ) {
        if (!empty($offer_post_url) && strpos($offer_post_url, $rule['shop']) !== false) {      
            $offer_post_url = 'https://www.second-network.com/promotion/click/id='.$rule['id'].'-yxz?param0='.rawurlencode($offer_post_url);
}    
    }

        return $offer_post_url; 
}
```

Comment: By content do you mean links in the the post editor content?

Comment: @mikerojas Yes, exactly.

Comment: The solution I provided below is used to filter the content.

Comment: Wait, what actually appears in the post editor or what appears in the output or both or what?

Comment: @CKMacLeod I think what appears in the post editor. In the output it should already be changed.

Comment: That's a different process... and more complicated. Do you want to change the URLs permanently in the database?

Comment: @CKMacLeod No, only the output should be changed. Now I understand, what do you asked. It should exactly work like in my function `link_change_custom` works for `offer_post_url`. In the editor the URLs should look normal.

Comment: Ok, you'll still need to provide some additional material/context. Apparently, there is a function of some type that changes url and id according to some rule, and you'll need to re-produce that rule (or set of conditions) in order to perform the right replacements, unless you know the precise set of possible urls to that will need to be replaced. The latter would be simplest. So, if you can add those to your example post, then a str_replace could handle it. If not, then you might to do a lot more code investigation.

Comment: @CKMacLeod The set of URLs are all domains in the array `$shops` like  apple.com,apple.com/test/, apple.com/example/example-1/ etc.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, that is what you need

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'replace_links_by_promotions' );
function replace_links_by_promotions( $content ) {
    $shop_ids = array(
        'apple.com'     => '1234',
        'microsoft.com' => '5678',
        'dell.com'      => '9876',
    );

    preg_match_all( '/https?:\/\/(www\.)?([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6})\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*)/', $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );

    foreach ( $matches[2] as $index => $match ) {
        if ( ! isset( $shop_ids[ $match[0] ] ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $offer_post_url = 'https://www.network.com/promotion/click/id=' . $shop_ids[ $match[0] ] . '-yxz?param0=' . rawurlencode( $matches[0][ $index ][0] );
        $content        = substr_replace( $content, $offer_post_url, $matches[0][ $index ][1], strlen( $matches[0][ $index ][0] ) );
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tested it with 2 or more apple.com URLs in the content, but only the first one is changed. Some links are total gone. Is it possible to combine my function and your function, so I wouldn't need to add all my arrays and foreachs  (336 lines).

Comment: I have not only one array with shops, that's why I have for every array one foreach for every affiliate network.

Comment: Give me please your data (URLs and content)

Comment: Here are all URLs. Your function should change not only the first matched URL. https://paiza.io/projects/zHPQv4D2XjhXJdE-_fDUYg

Comment: Maybe you have a solution like from CK_MacLeod. My changed version had some errors with other links. https://paiza.io/projects/8V8BJmt4pZOy4ihLjsyjRg

Answer (score 2):

I think this works. Note that, as written, it will match every "apple.", "dell.", and "microsoft." link in every type of content that uses the content filter - posts, pages, excerpts, many custom post types, etc. - so, if you don't really want that, and you very well may not, then the main replacement function will have to be conditionalized, and the regex function more precisely targeted..., and that can get complicated.

(Also, come to think of it, I'm not sure whether the quotes in the anchor tags that the Regex finds will require special handling. If this doesn't work, we can look at that, too. Or maybe switch to a DOM parser, like maybe I should have started out by doing... )

```
/** INITIATE FILTER FUNCTION **/
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpso_change_urls' ) ;

/**
 * PREG CALLBACK FUNCTION
 * Match Matches to id #s
 * and return replacement urls enclosed in quotes (as found)
 */ 
function wpso_found_urls( $matches ) { 

  //someone else probably has a v clever parsimonious way to do this next part
  //but at least this makes what's happening easy to read
  if ( strpos( $matches[0], 'apple' ) ) {

      $id = '1234' ;

  } 

  if ( strpos( $matches[0], 'microsoft' ) ) {

      $id = '5678' ;

  } 

  if ( strpos( $matches[0], 'dell' ) ) {

      $id = '9876' ;

  } 

  $raw_url = trim( $matches[0], '"' ) ;

  return '"https://www.network.com/promotion/click/id='. $id .'-yxz?param0='.rawurlencode( $raw_url) . '"' ; 

}

/** ENDURING A DREADFUL FATE USING REGEX TO PARSE HTML **/
function wpso_change_urls( $content ) { 

    $find_urls = array( 
        '/"+(http|https)(\:\/\/\S*apple.\S*")/',
        '/"+(http|https)(\:\/\/\S*microsoft.\S*")/',
        '/"+(http|https)(\:\/\/\S*dell.\S*")/',
    );

    return preg_replace_callback( $find_urls, 'wpso_found_urls', $content ) ; 

}
```

Returning (note: example prior to trimming quotes from the "raw URL" before encoded):

[image: Converted Links]

...from original (post editor) content like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would be great, if it could be much shorter and combining with my function `replace_links_by_promotions`, because I have over 300 shops and 7 foreach's for each affiliate network.. The quotes are really wrong, because they changed the URLs wrong: `%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.apple.com%2F%22`

Comment: I don't understand the last part about the wrong quotes. If the issue is just that the returned URLs need to be enclosed in quotes, that can be easily accomplished. If they need to be modified in some other way they can be, but you'd need to specify it more clearly. The same goes, even more, for scaling up and further rationalizing the routine, but at some point you may be going beyond the parameters for a StackOverflow question and looking at custom development work.

Comment: (I've edited the script to include enclosing quotes.)

Comment: How delete the enclosing quotes in the returned URLs? The result should be for example `https://www.network.com/promotion/click/id=1234-yxz?param0=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.apple.com`

Comment: FYI - the RegEx finds the url with the enclosing quotes, and I modified it to return them. To remove them, you'd... remove them from the line in the first function, from before "https" and (right after the single quote) and from the end of the statement - the entire `  . '"' `

Comment: The point being that in my testing it returns a well-formed link in page source... see edited answer.

Comment: The result should be  `<a href="https://www.network.com/promotion/click/id=1234-yxz?param0=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.apple.com">` without  `%22` between the apple Domain. Is it possible to use an array like in my function and combine my function with your code?

Comment: oh, I know what the problem is... hold on a sec - should work now

Comment: Maybe it is possible to use all my arrays for your function as well. Here is my whole code: paiza.io/projects/zHPQv4D2XjhXJdE-_fDUYg

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. As for your further question, I don't know for a fact that applying the filter will *not* work on arrays of that size being processed however many times per fresh page load, but I'd at least want to consider alternative approaches. Is there a reason for not saving the alterations you/'re making - the converted links - to the database more or less permanently in place of the originals? To say more I'd need to see the installation itself and understand a little better why this general method is the one you've settled on

Comment: This solution works, but maybe I could save some code or function. Could you check it? With this code other links (youtube.com embedded video or for example https://stackoverflow.com/) are not working, maybe I need a condition for the last function? paiza.io/projects/8V8BJmt4pZOy4ihLjsyjRg

Comment: Embeds are going to be a special question, and I don't understand how you're working with them. I also don't understand what you're referring to regarding stackoverflow.com. I'd remain concerned about implementing this type of solution - filtering on load - once scaled up to cover 300 shops, multiple networks, and other conditions with related part-processes..

Comment: I need a still a better solution. Maybe we could chat via Twitter or Facebook? Do you mean a solution like the function in my question is not possible for the content area?

Answer (score 0):

Might try using something like `the_content` filter to do this:

```
add_filter('the_content', function($content){

  // filter $content and replace urls
  $content = str_replace('http://old-url', 'http://new-url', $content);

  return $content;
});
```

More: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this solution I had already found. I need a solution like my function `link_change_custom`, where all links from a domain like apple.com would automatically  be changed like apple.com/test-123/, apple.com/test-123/example.html etc.

Comment: That’s exactly what this does.  You would need to swap the old url and new url for your case but this filter is exactly what you need if you are waning to programmatically swap those urls in the content.

Comment: I don't know how to swap the old urls. Could you write a function or better use my function  `link_change_custom` and expand it to change also the URLs in the content and not only  `$offer_post_url` ?

Comment: Do you have an idea?

Comment: I do have one idea... give me a bit to work something up.