# Wordpress: Automatically change URLs in the_content section

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

The solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60829912/wordpress-automatically-change-specific-urls-in-posts) isn't solving our problem. 
I have already a solution to change all links in a field form in our theme. I am using different arrays for every network like `$example_network_1` `$example_network_2` with a PHP foreach for each affiliate network.

Now I need a solution to use this same arrays for the content of a WordPress post.

This solution is working for one network, but it caused a 404e Error for YouTube videos. We put the URL from a YouTube video and WordPress generates automatically an embedded video. With the following code we get a **404 error iframe** or something like this.

**We need a solution for more than one network.**

I am very thankful for every help!

```
    $example_network_1 = array(
            array('shop'=>'shop1.com','id'=>'11111'),   
            array('shop'=>'shop2.co.uk','id'=>'11112'),
        );
    $example_network_2 = array(
            array('shop'=>'shop-x1.com','id'=>'11413'), 
            array('shop'=>'shop-x2.net','id'=>'11212'),
        );

    add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpso_change_urls' ) ;
    function wpso_found_urls( $matches ) { 
    global $example_network_1,$example_network_2;   
        foreach( $example_network_1 as $rule ) {
            if (strpos($matches[0], $rule['shop']) !== false) {
                $raw_url = trim( $matches[0], '"' ) ;
                return '"https://www.network-x.com/click/'. $rule['id'].'lorem_lorem='.rawurlencode($raw_url ) . '"';   
             }  

/*
      foreach( $example_network_2 as $rule ) {
            if (strpos($matches[0], $rule['shop']) !== false) {
                $raw_url = trim( $matches[0], '"' ) ;
                return '"https://www.network-y.com/click/'. $rule['id'].'lorem='.rawurlencode($raw_url ) . '"';     
             }  
*/
        }
    }
    function wpso_change_urls( $content ) {
        global $example_network_1,example_network_2;    
           return preg_replace_callback( '/"+(http|https)(\:\/\/\S*'. $example_network_1 ['shop'] .'\S*")/', 'wpso_found_urls', $content ) ;
    //     return preg_replace_callback( '/"+(http|https)(\:\/\/\S*'. $example_network_2 ['shop'] .'\S*")/', 'wpso_found_urls', $content ) ;
        }
```

Comment: Without seeing the content, it's unclear how this filter could be causing 404 errors on YouTube embeds. Could you provide the content in three forms: 1) what you're putting into WordPress on the back-end, 2) the correct output and 3) the error you're getting instead of the correct output?

Answer (score 4):

`autoembed` is hooked at `the_content` with priority 8 on `wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php:39`

Try to lower the priority of the `the_content` filter so that the URL replacement happens before the embed, something like this:

```php
add_filter( 'the_content', function ( $content ) {
    /*
     * Here, we define the replacements for each site in the network.
     * '1' = main blog
     * '2' = site 2 in the network, and so on
     *
     * To add more sites, just add the key number '3', etc
     */
    $network_replacements = [
        '1' => [
            [ 'shop' => 'shop1.com', 'id' => '11111' ],
            [ 'shop' => 'shop2.co.uk', 'id' => '11112' ],
        ],
        '2' => [
            [ 'shop' => 'shop-x1.com', 'id' => '11413' ],
            [ 'shop' => 'shop-x2.net', 'id' => '11212' ],
        ]
    ];

    // Early bail: Current blog ID does not have replacements defined
    if ( ! array_key_exists( get_current_blog_id(), $network_replacements ) ) {
        return $content;
    }

    $replacements = $network_replacements[ get_current_blog_id() ];

    return preg_replace_callback( '/"+(http|https)(\:\/\/\S*' . $replacements['shop'] . '\S*")/', function( $matches ) use ( $replacements ) {
        foreach ( $replacements as $rule ) {
            if ( strpos( $matches[0], $rule['shop'] ) !== false ) {
                $raw_url = trim( $matches[0], '"' );

                return '"https://www.network-x.com/click/' . $rule['id'] . 'lorem_lorem=' . rawurlencode( $raw_url ) . '"';
            }
        }
    }, $content );
}, 1, 1 );
```

This is not a copy and paste solution, but should get you going. You might need to tweak your "preg_replace_callback" code, but you said it was working so I just left it is it was.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It works. But I need a solution, where different arrays for every partner network or even only one domain for an advertiser. For some networks I need to rawurlencode the URL and for others I didn't it. For two networks I didn't use an ID for the domains. In my example I have add a second network in comments, because it wasn't working. A function could only return one result. '1' and '2' are in networks and I would like to call them with strings and not number for the overview.

Comment: With your version all images in `the_content` are not displayed. The images didn't come from the domains in the array, they are on our server.

Comment: It is not only one network. They are over 400 domains and it my list will grow. Here is the whole code, where the URLS are changed in a theme field. All URLs should also be changed int `the_content`: [link](https://paiza.io/projects/H-fYyHMJizdLBHleUy3L_w?language=php)

Comment: Do you have an idea ?

Comment: You need to change `the_content` in 400 different websites?

Comment: No,  only in one website, where all URLs in the arrays should be changed.

Comment: The keys in the array in my example are the network IDs. The arrays, the replacement to be made. If in some of them you need to run `rawurlencode`, run it in the array value.

Comment: Images are not loading with your code. Could you expand your code, where links from 2 networks are changing (e.g. `[1]` in `https://www.network-x.com/click/...` and `[2]` in` https://www.network-y.com/lorem/...` ) and is it possible to rename the networks with words and not numbers?

Comment: @Grischa You could try to use the blog URL instead of the ID. Something like this: https://pastebin.com/81dJSDcU

Comment: @Grischa about the issue, I didn't understand very well the issue you're having. If you could provide a detailed example, possibly with a pastebin of the output you're getting and what you're trying to achieve, maybe I can help you.

Comment: Maybe we could give you a login, if you like. Your Pastebin code is also only returning the links only for one network (e.g. example.com and not another return links from some-site.com). I  have send you the whole code, which works for the field in my theme. All this link-changes should work for the `the_content` section. Like I said, with your code our mages aren't visible anymore.

Comment: Your PasteBin didn't change any links. Example: in `the_content` is a link like `apple.com/iphone11/` this link should change to `network-x.com/click/id-123.rawurlencode('apple.com/iphone11/')` and another link from an other ntwork like `example1.com` should  change to  `website-y.com/click/id-1424`

Comment: Do you understand, what we need?

Answer (score 0):

If preventing the wp auto-embed works, then just add this line to your theme `functions.php`

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', array( $GLOBALS['wp_embed'], 'autoembed' ), 8 );
```

Comment: We want to use the auto-embed function for YouTube videos, but a code for changing specific URLs in the_content section shouldn't crash this.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote solution without test. Your code is hard to test without your site but I think that problem is with regex. Callback is hard to debugging. My version below.

First step, change your structure. I suspect that domains are unique.  One dimensional array is more useful.

```php
$domains =  array(
            'shop1.com'=>'11111',   
            'shop2.co.uk'=>'11112',
            'shop-x1.com'=>'11413', 
            'shop-x2.net'=>'11212',
        );
```

Next:

```php
$dangerouschars  = array(
  '.'=>'\.',

);
function wpso_change_urls( $content ) {
   global $domains,$dangerouschars;
   foreach($domains as $domain=>$id){
      $escapedDomain = str_replace(array_keys($dangerouschars),array_values($dangerouschars), $domain);

     if (preg_match_all('/=\s*"(\s*https?:\/\/(www\.)?'.$escapedDomain.'[^"]+)\s*"\s+/mi', $content, $matches)){
        // $matches[0] - ="https://example.com"
        // $matches[1] - https://example.com
        for($i = 0; $i<count($matches[0]); $i++){
                $matchedUrl = $matches[1][$i];
                $url = rawurlencode($matchedUrl);
                //is very important to replace with ="..."
                $content = str_replace($matches[0][$i], "=\"https://www.network-x.com/click/{$id}lorem_lorem={$url}\" ", $content);
        }
     }
   }
   return $content;
}
```

[Example script](https://pastebin.pl/view/b8a97323)

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but it doesn't work.  I didn't unterstand why you have add the array `$dangerouschars`.    In my test I have add the missing   `add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpso_change_urls' ) ;` I can use one dimensional arrays, but I need a solution, where different arrays for every partner network or even only one domain for an advertiser.  For some networks I need to rawurlencode the URL  and for others I didn't it.  For two networks I didn't use an ID for the domains. My script only change the URLs in a field form my Wordpress theme.

Comment: Please have a look for my whole code for every partner: https://paiza.io/projects/9a0m-brPc6B4vBVLcqzgMA

Answer (score 0):

i have got the same error. The problem is at the 'x' letter. WordPress exchange it on `the_content()` function if the link aren't inside any tag like img or a.

So the link that must be website.com/taxes.jpg for example it turns into website.com/ta×es.jpg.

Im looking for a solution but could find it yet.

My temp solution were:

```
$url_img = str_replace('&times;', 'x', $url_img);
```

Maybe it helps someone.

Comment: Do you have a solution, or are you looking for one? Please [edit] your answer to be a full answer, as it currently looks like a question.