# Find and replace url in wordpress content

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been stuck with a problem in Wordpress.

I want to replace all non amp urls to amp but except some pages.

I have written a function which was working well previously but stopped working when I put the condition to give exemption to some urls.

This is my code. I want to remove my about page to be replaced from the new url.

```
function replace_anchor_text($text){
    preg_match_all("/https?\:\/\/mysiteurl.com[^\" ]+/i", $text, $match);
    $count = count($match[0]);
    $i = 0;
    if($count == 0 ) {
        $newtext = $text;
    } else {
        while($i <= $count-1) {
        
            if (strpos($match[0][$i], 'amp/') !== true || strpos($match[0][$i], 'mysiteurl.com/') !== false || strpos($match[0][$i], 'aboutpage/') !== true ) {
                $newtext = str_replace('/"','/amp/"',$text);
            }
            $matches[] = $match[0][$i];
            $i++;
        }
    }
    

    echo $newtext;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'replace_anchor_text');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'replace_anchor_text');
```

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all `echo $newtext;` looks fishy, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/ and esp. compare with the example there and the use of `return`. Additionally scan the existing answers (esp. those with a bounty) for existing approaches with `the_content` and similar filters (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61330343/367456).

Answer (score 0):

I had to simplfy your code a bit because it was a little difficult to read

```
function replace_anchor_text($text){    
    preg_match_all("/https?\:\/\/mysiteurl.com[^\" ]+/i", $text, $match);    
    $count = count($match[0]);    
    
    $newtext = $text;
    if($count !== 0 ) {
        $matchString = $match[0][$count-1];
        
        if (!strpos($matchString, 'amp/') && !strpos($matchString, 'mysiteurl.com/') && !strpos($matchString, 'aboutpage/') ) {
            $newtext = str_replace('/"','/amp/"', $newtext);
        }        
    }
    
    echo $newtext;
    
}
```

There were a few issues

```
strpos($match[0][$i], 'mysiteurl.com/') !== false
```

Based on your description and the way i'm reading your code, this should be `!== true` or

```
!strpos($match[0][$i], 'mysiteurl.com/')
```

Also

```
if (strpos($match[0][$i], 'amp/') !== true || strpos($match[0][$i], 'mysiteurl.com/') !== false || strpos($match[0][$i], 'aboutpage/') !== true )
```

This is saying `if`

- match doesn't contain `amp/`
- `OR`
- match does contain `mysiteurl.com/`
- `OR`
- match doesn't contain `aboutpage/`

Then change the text, if these are exclusions, then you only want to add the amp/ if they're all not true eg:

- match doesn't contain `amp/`
- `AND`
- match doesn't contain `mysiteurl.com/`
- `AND`
- match doesn't contain `aboutpage/`

So replacing the `||` with an `&&` - however the middle clause also needs to change to check for false instead of not false as above